# OMNeT++: Precedence of Parameters in omnetpp.ini File. The way I take for creating specific values causes errors

Tags: simulation

The precedence section in chapter 9.3.1 tells me that I should apply the special cases first and then the general ones.

```
[General]
*.host[0].waitTime = 5ms   # specifics come first
*.host[3].waitTime = 6ms
*.host[*].waitTime = 10ms  # catch-all comes last
```

I have following lines in the omnetpp.ini file:

```
**.server[*].tcpApp[0].port = 1000

**.pods[0..1].**.server[*].tcpApp[0].port = 80

**.pods[2..3].**.server[*].tcpApp[0].port = 21
```

This code works, but every server has 1000 when checking the parameter and not the special cases 80 and 21. So I want it to look like that:

```
**.pods[0..1].**.server[*].tcpApp[0].port = 80

**.pods[2..3].**.server[*].tcpApp[0].port = 21

**.server[*].tcpApp[0].port = 1000
```

Yet, this creates an error, which consists of a null pointer exception in the TCP module of the StandardHost module my server is build on.

In the ned file, the parameter is declared like this:

```
    int port = default(1000); // port number to listen on
```

Leaving that catch-all line out causes the error too. Only taking the last line above the other two makes it possible to let the simulation run through.

An example for the port parameter can be found in TCPServerHostApp.ned from INET. I want to assign different ports for different services which should run on the servers.

What is your advice for me, to apply those parameters correctly? Is there an error in the way I set the parameters, or do I need to set the ports somewhere during the initialization process myself (which would make no sense to me)?

Edit:
The karma system does not allow me to answer the question yet, so here is the cause of my problem:

Well, the problem was at another place. When connecting a new socket with connect(ipaddr, port), I got the wrong port from the job request message.

At the traffic generation module, I read the wrong port for connection to the server, which caused an error, as the port being used was always the default = 1000 instead of 80 or 21.

The servers expected 80 or 21, causing a crash when the socket tried to connect with port 1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to add this here as well, so everybody sees I found the error.

Well, the problem was at another place. When connecting a new socket with `connect(ipaddr, port)`, I got the wrong port from a job request message.

At the traffic generation module, I read the wrong port for connection to the server, which caused an error, as the port being used was always the default `(= 1000)` instead of `80 or 21`.

The servers expected `80 or 21`, causing a crash, when the socket tried to connect with `1000`.